# SASS box-shadow Mixin crashing Internet Explorer 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass

I'm using SASS with Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3 in RVM.

My issue is that, for one reason or another, my SASS box-shadow mixin causes Internet Explorer 8 to crash on page load, no error from IE, just completely closes.  If I remove the mixin, it opens perfectly...The mixin looks like:

```
@mixin boxShadow($params) {
  -moz-box-shadow: $params;
  -webkit-box-shadow: $params;
  box-shadow: $params;
}
```

I have this at the top of my application.scss

`@import 'mixins';`

I'm using the mixin as such:

`@include boxShadow(0px 1px 3px #999);`

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Are you using straight up SASS or Compass? Can you post the CSS output, and test if that by itself crashes the page?

Comment: Just SASS, no compass.  Wrote the mixins myself.  How do you propose I test the CSS crashing, just include it in a blank HTML document and open with IE8?

Minimized CSS: https://gist.github.com/3140201

Comment: Yeah, create a static page and apply the box shadow mixin to an element, isolate the rule and see what is breaking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an old version of respond.min.js blowing things up!